# Split tuple if key is empty and add correspondence value to its previous tuple value

Tags: python, list, tuples

Here i have a list of tuples,whenever key is empty i want to add correspondence value to its previous tuple value.

I am able to achieve this in traditional way, but it looks ugly,
Is there any pythonic way to achieve the same ?

input :

```
data= [('A', 12), ('', 1), ('B', 12), ('', 1), ('C', 12), ('', 1), ('D', 13)]
```

expected output :

```
[13, 26, 39, 52]
```

My CODE:

```
data = [('A', 12), ('', 1), ('B', 12), ('', 1), ('C', 12), ('', 1), ('D', 13)]
init = 0 ; splitdata = []
for i in data:
    init = init+i[1]
    if i[0] == '':
        splitdata.append(init)
splitdata.append(init)
print(splitdata)
[13, 26, 39, 52]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
reduce(
        lambda lst,item: (((item[0] != '') and lst) or lst[:-1]) + [lst[-1] + item[1]],
        colLabelGrouped[1:],
        [colLabelGrouped[0][1]] )
```

This reduction...

- starts with an initial list consisting of the value of the first item in `colLabelGrouped`, then
- reduces the remaining items in `colLabelGrouped` by...

  - appending the value of each item in turn added to the last element of the list being produced to *either*...

    - the complete list (if the item's key is not empty) or
    - the list minus the last element (if the item's key is empty).

Comment: edited to be an actual working answer.  This is what I get for typing answers directly here and not into a python prompt where I can test it :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly shorter way of doing it using the accumulate function and list-comprehensions (it might be more readable too):

```
colLabelGrouped = [('A', 12), ('', 1), ('B', 12), ('', 1), ('C', 12), ('', 1), ('D', 13)]

from itertools import accumulate
cumsum = list(accumulate([x[1] for x in colLabelGrouped]))
result = [cumsum[i] for i,x  in enumerate(colLabelGrouped) if x[0] == ""] 

if colLabelGrouped[-1][0] != "":
    result.append(cumsum[-1])

print(result)
```

Comment: while the OP's sample data did not include this case, their question implied that having multiple blank keys in a row would be a possibility that needs to be accounted for.  For example: `[('A', 10), ('', 2), ('', 1), ('B', 12), ('', 1), ('C', 12), ('', 1), ('D', 13)]`.  Can you rework your answer to account for this?  I've never used the `itertools` stuff, so I'm interested :)

Comment: @JEarls Ok, now I'm confused ... what I understood from the expected behaviour was "whenever there's a blank compute the cumulative sum and append it to the result" ... what result do you expect from that example ?

Comment: I read `whenever key is empty i want to add correspondence value to its previous tuple value` and read an implied `and remove the tuple with the empty key`.  If that implication is correct, then the *next* tuple with an empty key would also add its correspondence value to the same previous (non-empty-key) tuple.

Comment: Now that I read their code sample, I realize my extra implication was incorrect.  Never mind.

Answer (score 1):

Using reduce you can do something like this:

```
from functools import reduce

data = [('A', 12), ('', 1), ('B', 12), ('', 1), ('C', 12), ('', 1), ('D', 13)]
splitdata = reduce(
    lambda res, i: res[:-1] + [res[-1] + i[1]] * (2 if i[0] == '' else 1),
    data,
    [0]
)
print(splitdata)
```

Comment: Is this is python-3 specific?  (the `x if y else z` syntax?)

Comment: Some googling tells me it has been added since python 2.5.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'm an old fart who still is used to programming python 2.4. :)